# CentOS7 ネットワーク設定について

Tags: centos, network

CentOS7のサーバー構築をしています。
IPアドレスを固定にするため、イーサネットの設定を変更し、現状`ip addr`するとこんな感じです。(一部伏せます)

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp8s0f0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP     qlen 1000
link/ether 00:--:--:--:--:-- brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet ”設定したIP”/32 brd ”設定したIP” scope global 接続名
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ----::---:----:----:----/64 scope link
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

これで、sshd_configで一時的にPasswordAuthenticationをyesにし、

```
firewall-cmd --add-port=22/tcp --zone=public --permanent
```

を実行し、

```
firewall-cmd --reload
systemctl restart NetworkManager
systemctl restart network
systemctl restart sshd
```

して、外部からsshしてみると、Connection timed outします。

ポートは開いています。

```
[----@---- ~]$ ss -tln
State      Recv-Q Send-Q        Local Address:Port          Peer          Address:Port
LISTEN     0      128                       *:22                       *:*
LISTEN     0      100               127.0.0.1:25                       *:*
LISTEN     0      128                      :::22                      :::*
LISTEN     0      100                     ::1:25                      :::*
```

サーバーと同じLAN内からアクセスすると、普通に接続できます。
ということはこれはローカルアドレスなんですか？

外部からもsshで接続したいのですが、いまいちどうすればいいかわかりません。

知識不足ですみませんがよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

IPv6 はわからないので（すみません）IPv4 という前提です。

> サーバーと同じLAN内からアクセスすると、普通に接続できます。

ということですのでプライベートIPを割り当てているのだと思いますが
（ちなみにプライベートIPの場合、隠してもあまり意味はありません）、

・外部（インターネット側？）からは、どうやって（どこに）アクセスしていますか？
・外部とサーバの間にファイアーウォールはありますか？
・ある場合、ファイアーウォールで ssh を許可していますか？

【追加】
[http://www.atmarkit.co.jp/aig/06network/privateip.html]
ここに該当するアドレスが振られていれば、「プライベートアドレス」です。

> centOS7のfirewalldが動いています。
>   ただ、22番ポートは通るようになっています。

ここで言うファイアーウォール(F/W)は、そのサーバホスト上の
仕組みではなく、ネットワーク上の物理的な機器です。

もう少し構成状況を正確に記載されたほうがいいと思います。
例えば私の自宅から（どこかの）企業の中にあるサーバに ssh で
入りたい場合は、おおむね以下の様な構成になるはずです。

[自宅PC]--[自宅の無線ルータ]--[企業のF/W]--[対象サーバ]

[対象サーバ]にプライベートアドレスが割り当てられている場合、
自宅内からはそのアドレス空間は見えませんので、何らかのグローバルIP
が必要です。VPSの場合はグローバルIPが割り当てられますので、
 ssh ユーザ名@グローバルIP
で接続が可能です。

> だとすると、グローバルアドレスの設定はできるのでしょうか？
>   静的NATとかする形になるんでしょうか？

もし上記の構成例に近いのであれば、[企業のF/W]で[対象サーバ]に
対応するグローバルIPを割り当て、[企業のF/W]の設定で静的NATを
行なうことが考えられます。この方式で実現する場合は、[対象サーバ]
の設定はそのままでOKです。

Comment: すみません、IPv4です。 > ということですのでプライベートIPを割り当てているのだと思いますが やはりそうですよね。 > ・外部（インターネット側？）からは、どうやって（どこに）アクセスしていますか？ インターネット側なんでしょうか、別のLANというか、
たとえば会社と自宅という例をとると、
自宅LAN→会社内のサーバーというところでしょうか。 アクセスしたいサーバーのIPを192.168.1.2としたら、
自宅から ssh user@192.168.1.2 としようとしていました。今考えてみると、ローカルアドレスならWANからどこを指してるかわからないからアクセスできないですよね。よくわからない・・・ > ・外部とサーバの間にファイアーウォールはありますか？
> ・ある場合、ファイアーウォールで ssh を許可していますか？ あります。centOS7のfirewalldが動いています。
ただ、22番ポートは通るようになっています。 たとえばVPSをレンタルすると、レンタル会社から、IPアドレスは---.--.--.---です。
という通知が来ますよね。あれはグローバルアドレスだから、
手配してもらった状態でssh可能ということですか？ だとすると、グローバルアドレスの設定はできるのでしょうか？
静的NATとかする形になるんでしょうか？

Comment: 失礼いたしました。サーバー構成は以下です。
[自宅(対象)サーバー]-[自宅ルーター]-[自宅firewall?]-[社内ルーター]-[社内PC]です。
なるほど、つまりグローバルIPはFirewallで設定可能なのですね。
ちなみに、いろいろ試しているうちに、うまくいきそうな設定を行うことができました。というのは、1. [自宅Firewall]で22番を解放 2. [ルーター]で22番を解放※意味ありますか？ 3. 自宅グローバルアドレスの22番でパケットを受信したら、[自宅サーバー]のローカルアドレス:22に転送するよう[自宅ルーター]で設定。

その後、 https://www.cman.jp/network/support/port.html にて22番が解放されているか確認したところ、”接続できました” となりました。自宅と会社で物理的な距離があるため、即座にsshできるか確認できないのですが、この理屈は通りますか？

何度も何度も申し訳ございません。

Comment: 会社から自宅の ssh サーバに接続するのですね？
であれば、自宅側はそれで OK ぽいです。

後は、[社内ルータ] で、社内から外部（インターネット）に対して
Dynamic NAT で 22 番が通っていれば、社内から
 ssh ユーザ名@自宅のグローバルIP
で接続可能かと思います。

自宅内から自宅の ssh サーバに接続する場合は
 ssh ユーザ名@プライベートIPアドレス
となります。

Comment: 先ほど、社内から接続してみたところ、無事サーバーを発見できたようです！証明書の登録を忘れていて、ログインはできませんでしたが・・・(苦笑
長らく付き合っていただいて本当にありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

プライベートアドレスで運用しているサーバにインターネット越しにsshしたいということだと思います。やり方はお使いのネットワーク構成によっていろいろ方法がありえる、が正解となります。

例えばサーバが自宅やオフィスにあり、ブロードバンドルータでインターネットに接続しているとします。ブロードバンドルータはWAN側(インターネット側)にグローバルIP、LAN側にプライベートIPが付いており、サーバもそのLAN側にあるとします。このとき、ブロードバンドルータにあるポート転送の機能を使うことで、グローバルIPの22番(SSH)に接続してきたパケットをLAN側のサーバの22番に転送する、ということが可能です。(私の知る限りよほど変なルータでない限りはこの機能が付いてます)。

これを実現するためには、WAN側のアドレスを知る必要があります。ルータの管理画面のどこかに表示されているはずですので、調べてみてください。ポート転送機能もルータの管理画面から設定しますが、製品によっては「ゲームサーバ機能」「ポートフォワード機能」など呼び方は様々ですので、まずは管理画面を見てみてください。

あと、まれにプロバイダによってはWAN側がプライベートIPになっている場合があります。この場合は外部からのポート転送はできませんのでご注意ください。

Comment: なるほど、わかりやすかったです。ようするに、ルーターから静的にポートフォワードする設定を追加すればいいわけですか。
さっそく行ってみました。
たぶん「ポートマッピング」のことですよね。
グローバルIPの入力フィールドはありませんでしたが、変換ポートの設定と、LANアドレスの設定がありました。

IPアドレスをサーバーのローカルアドレスに、
待機ポートを22、変換ポートを22に設定しました。

https://www.cman.jp/network/support/port.html
ここを使って、ルーターのグローバルアドレス:22に接続できることを確認しました。
が、確認する術は直接外部から接続してみるしかありませんか？
物理距離があるので、できればサーバー本体のあるうちに確認したいです。

現在はルートログイン不可、パスワード認証不可、証明書ログイン可になっています。
ssh user@グローバルIPをしても同一LAN内からだと接続できませんでした。
これは何か設定が間違っているからでしょうか？

Comment: LANの内側からWAN側のグローバルIPを指定してもうまくいきません。きちんと理論を理解しているわけではないのですが、ルーティング上の都合か何かだと思われます。私も自宅サーバで今回の件と同様の設定をしていますが、試すときはやはり外から繋ぎます。例えば私は幸いなことにFOMAのUSBアダプタを持っているので、PCをLANから切断してFOMAでつなぎ直してグローバルIPにアクセス可能かを試したりします。あるいはスマホをお持ちなら、スマホ用のSSHクライアントもありますので、それを使うことも考えられます。もしそれすらもなければ…、例えばAmazon EC2やSoftLayerなどのサービスを試用版で契約して一時的に外にサーバを立ててそこからSSHしてみるなど、もあるかもしれません。

Comment: テザリングは検討しましたが、契約していなかったのであきらめました。
スマホ用なんてあるのですね！ちょっと探してみます。
そうですね、VPSを一つレンタルします。